# Debian: Plymouth apply new Theme

Tags: debian, splash-screen, boot

I'm suing Debian Squeeze 6.0.7
I have installed Plymouth to have a graphical image be shown at boot instead of the system calls.

I can change the default THEMES that came with Plymouth without a problem.
`/usr/sbin/plymouth-set-default-theme solar`
`update-initramfs -u`

this changes the THEME to solar, and if I changed `solar` to `space-fun` then I get the space-fun theme. I have made a duplicate of the `solar/` and have renamed it to `mySplash/`. Inside the directory, I created my own image and saved it as the same name of `star.png` the `solar.plymouth` file was changed to `mySplah.plymouth`

my `mySplash.plymouth` file looks like this:

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=mySplash
Description=<some Text>
ModuleName=mySplahflare

ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/mySplash
```

I went to `/usr/lib/plymouth/` copied the `space-flare.so` file and renamed the duplicate to `mySplashflares.so` just so the .plymouth file had something to reference and then tried to use the above commands to change to my new theme. The result is the blue text progress bar that appears at the bottom as if the video card driver settings were not configured properly.

Q: What else do i need to do to be able to see my "custom" plymouth Theme??

Answer (score 0):

Problem: You shouldn't Capitalise the name of the theme files.

Copy your theme directory to /usr/share/plymouth/themes

If the directory name contains any capital letters, get rid of them and change the name such that the directory name is in all-lower-case. Also, get rid of spaces and such in the directory name. Inside the theme directory, you will see a .plymouth file. Open it up in a text editor and change the paths in it to /usr/share/plymouth/themes instead of /lib/plymouth/themes. Save the file and the theme is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try [Plymouth Manager](https://github.com/x1unix/plymouth-manager) tool. It allows to install, select and preview themes.